# How to set icon in application base only on name

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, xcode4

Is there a way to set app icon only based by name. For example I know if I name files **Default.png** and **Default@2x.png** and add it to my project they became my Splash/Default screen. What about App Icon?

Second way: Maybe i may declared name somwhere in plist/app ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chose the names for all those resources in the info.plist file of your target.

Comment: Oh, thanks, You know maybe how to put directory in it? I want to add path to resource directory from my app. Is this possible? (*blue* directory, not group)

Answer (score 1):

App Icon should be named **Icon.png** and **Icon@2x.png**

Comment: by default i have [appname]Icon.png. Now i know it from dasdom solution.

Comment: Take a look here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1686/_index.html It says `Icon.png` is **required**. You can set it in info.plist or your target's summary page...

Answer (score 0):

You can also select image from anywhere as followings:
[image]